# How do I cycle a JS function in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a title on my website and I want to change a word in the title every 2 seconds. I did this by putting an html element in Elementor with the following code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <h1> Test sentence <span id="change_title_text">WordToChange</span></h1>
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
    var messages = [],
        index = 0;

    messages.push('Word 1');
    messages.push('Word 2');

    function cycle() {
        $('#change_title_text').html(messages[index]);
        index++;

        if (index === messages.length) {
            index = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(cycle, 2000);
    }

    cycle();
});
</script>
```

This works fine and as expected. However, I would really like to keep all my JS code in a file to make it easier to find and to keep the code more structured. I have a custom JS file which has code since before which works, so I know that it runs properly. I tried to copy/paste the code from the html element to my custom JS file like this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';

    script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
$(function () {
    var messages = [],
        index = 0;

    messages.push('Word 1');
    messages.push('Word 2');

    function cycle() {
        $('#change_title_text').html(messages[index]);
        index++;

        if (index === messages.length) {
            index = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(cycle, 2000);
    }

    cycle();
});
```

And the JS file is loaded in my child themes functions.php like this:

```
function custom_js_script_enqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_script('mycustomjs', CHILD_THEME_URI . '/assets/js/my-custom-js.js', array(), '1.0.0', false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_js_script_enqueue');
```

What do I have to do to make the JS code run as in the html element? I tried to move JS from footer to header by changing the last element of wp_enqueue_script to false but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Change `$(` to `jQuery(` in in your script

Comment: @Vel Didn't work :(

Comment: Any error in console and js path is correct?

Comment: @Vel No errors, path worked from the custom html element so it should be same

Comment: I mean `my-custom-js.js` path is correct?

Comment: @Vel Yes, other code in that function is running correctly, e.g. my sticky header

Comment: Share your website URL if possible?

Comment: @Vel, it is localhost only. I read something about using SetInterval isntead, is that a better solution?

Comment: Yes You should use `setInterval`

Comment: @Vel , alright I will look into that

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var messages = [],
        index = 0;

    function cycle() {
        jQuery('#change_title_text').html(messages[index % messages.length]);
        index++;
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        messages.push('Word 1');
        messages.push('Word 2');
        setInterval(cycle, 2000);
    });

});
```

Comment: The function itself works fine. Your function works too. But Elementor still stucks on load.

Comment: What do you mean by 'stuck'? do you see anything in the Console?

Comment: It is stuck on loading. In console I get the same error as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72407238/uncaught-typeerror-e-dispatchevent-is-not-a-function-elementor-wordpress-fronte

Comment: You shouldn't add jQuery, as it is already bundled with WordPress (try removing "var script = document.createElement('script');script.type = 'text/javascript';script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js';document.body.appendChild(script);" from your code)

Comment: removing those and then the word change don't work anymore.

Comment: and what does the console say?

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

Comment: where are you using $? try replacing every '$' with 'jQuery'

Comment: I didn't have any $. But when I put one in "jQuery(function ($) {..." it suddenly got no errors and works... :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248874/discussion-between-hillel-and-eligolf).